# I am unable to ping my public IPv4 address

Tags: windows

I am unable to ping my public IPv4 address for some reason.

Currently for testing purposes my Windows firewall and routers firewall are both disabled and I'm still unable to get the correct response.

Does anyone know any potential reasons as to why this could be happening:

Additional details

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.8
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%19
                                    192.168.1.1
```

Comment: its common to configure a router to not respond to echo requests on the WAN (or block the requests via firewall), to prevent enumeration of hosts by IP scanners. additionally, some ISPs use indirect methods to connect public IPs to internal ones, so often times the port that uses your public IP address may be upstream in ISPs network, rather than just being the WAN port on your router.

Comment: Are you trying to ping from inside your network or from outside your network?

Comment: I tried pinging  my public address both from inside and outside and it didnt work  in both cases

Comment: Are you assuming that `192.168.1.8` is the public IP? Or where do you get your public IP? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: im assuming my public ip to be the public ipv4 address (not 192.168.1.8) - the thing you get when you look up whats my ip @harrymc

Comment: We could be more certain if it's CGNAT if you told us what your public IP is [omit the last digit if you like]

Comment: My public ip is 223.190.82.13x

Comment: OK, that doesn't look like a CGNAT address. You may need to ask your ISP if their routers accept inbound ping. ISPs block all kinds of inbound connections for all kinds of reasons.

Comment: also later on i tried to host a minecraft server to see what would happen but for some reason i couldnt log into to the server